# Using Command Line Arguments in C# Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, command-line-arguments

I'm running C# unit tests to run selenium tests and in this I need to sign into different user accounts. I'm trying retrieve the username and password as command line arguments but cannot find a way to do this in C# visual studio unit tests.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Part of my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Login()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.baseURL);    
        driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName").SendKeys(userID);
        driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_Password").SendKeys(password);
        driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton").Click();
    }
```

Here the "userID" and the "password should be my command line arguments.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Properties > Debug -- under Start Options has a spot you can add command line arguments

Comment: Can you describe the scenario after getting user/password from commandline.

Comment: I'm using Jenkins where I can enter Command Line Arguments but I'm not sure how to access those arguments within my testing.

Comment: If i understand you, you need to pass arguments to external program within the unit test, you can use Process Class ProcessInfo to pass arguments and catch results.Is it you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a unit test you should not use variable input from the command line but have it be constant.

For example your test should be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Login()
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.baseURL);
    driver
        .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName")
        .SendKeys("testuser");
    driver
        .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_Password")
        .SendKeys("testpass");
    driver
        .FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton")
        .Click();
}
```

You should then ensure that the database is properly mocked or initialized with the correct state before the test is run.

Comment: That was my initial process, but I've since been instructed to change it to command line arguments. This is because there are many of us on the team so instead of just one user name and password being used we should be able to change it so everyone can check their own.

Comment: You're going down a bad path there. Unit tests should not be running against a shared database. You should be mocking the database for each test or initializing it to a known state before the test.

Comment: Okay, thanks Justin. Out of curiosity, why should tests not be ran against a shared database?

Comment: Non-determinism is the enemy of unit testing. If you have a database, which can be accessed by multiple people at any given time then that state is non-deterministic. Furthermore, unit testing is intended to be very fast, to give a developer a fast development loop, accessing a live database will be very slow. It will also prevent the tests from running in certain places (different network configurations). The tests should be more isolated than that.

Comment: So I looking into it more the database I'm working with is a mocked database of the real one as it is to just test these certain things. Since this is the case and also I'm trying to still learn if what I'm trying to do is possible, is there a way to reach command line arguments from unit tests?

Comment: To anyone who's interested in what I ended up doing: 
I ended up having Jenkins execute a batch file that created a .txt file with my credentials and then parsed that file in Visual Studio. This way we can all enter our credentials in Jenkins and don't have to mess with the code at all.

Comment: @justin.m.chase I write unit tests to try and duplicate real world problems. Two I have at the moment are A) a routine is not reading command line arguments as expected and B) some strange combination of DB info causing incorrect results,. Maybe that doesn't match your definition of Unit Testing, but I use it as a framework to get the real world problems sorted.